# Ajax post fails in spring-mvc liferay portlet app

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

i have a liferay app than runs ok
im trying to send to the server an ajax post but it fails
actually the server responds ok and i can see the response in firefox developer tools
however on debugging i just get Exception "typeError"

he is my client and server code

```
function getChildClaims(father){
    var value = father.value;
    var url  = $("#ajaxUrl").val();

    $.post(url,{'fatherId' : value})
    .success(function(){
            alert("good");
    })
    .error(function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

}

and my server code

```
@RequestMapping(params="action=getChildClaimsAjax")
    public void getChildClaims(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response) throws NumberFormatException, EcareException_Exception, IOException{
            List<CustomerClaim> childClaims =ServiceFactory.getCustomerService().getClaimByFatherId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("fatherId")));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(childClaims);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write(json);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<portlet:resourceURL/>` as ajaxURL(in your case) in jsp.jspf, in you are referring.

Instead of @RequestMapping annotation use @ResourceMapping, this change would resolve your issue.

Comment: Im using the resourceURL the problem is not in the server,i resolved it by using the ajax method  and specifying the datatype : json